# GEE: subtract not a function

Tags: google-earth-engine, evi

I tried to do calculations for 2 dataset of EVI on different year. I got an error message evi2020.subtract is not a function.
The code is below

```
    var countries = Indonesia

var Nama_Provinsi = ['Kalimantan Selatan'] 
var geometry = countries.filter(ee.Filter.inList('NAME_1', Nama_Provinsi));
var area1 = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31'));
var evi2020 = dataset.select('EVI');
var eviVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 8000.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};
Map.setCenter(116, -3, 8);


Map.addLayer(evi2020, eviVis, 'EVI20');

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2010-01-01', '2010-12-31'));
var evi2010 = dataset.select('EVI');
var eviVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 8000.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};
Map.setCenter(116, -3, 8);


Map.addLayer(evi2010, eviVis, 'EVI10');

var selisihevi = evi2020.subtract(evi2010);
Map.addLayer(selisihevi.clip(area1), {min: -0.5, max: 0.5, palette:'blue, green, yellow, red'}, "Selisih EVI");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to apply `subtract()` to an `ee.ImageCollection`, however `subtract()` only works for `ee.Image`.

The way you can go from an Image Collection to a single image is by **reducing**, using for example `first()` or `mean()`:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1').select('EVI')

var evi2020 = dataset.filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31')
var evi2010 = dataset.filterDate('2010-01-01', '2010-12-31');

// Reduce the image collections to a single image

var evi2020_mean = evi_2020.mean()
var evi2010_mean = evi_2010.mean()

var difference = evi2020_mean.subtract(evi2010_mean);
```

On the other hand, if you want to subtract every Image from one day of year in 2020 from the same day in 2010 it is a bit more complicated. To do this you would have to **map over the image collection** (Note that this only works if the acquisitions are on exactly the same date every year).

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1').select('EVI')

var evi2020 = dataset.filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31')
var evi2010 = dataset.filterDate('2010-01-01', '2010-12-31');

var doy_difference = evi2020.map(function(image){
  var date = image.date()
  var doy = ee.Number.parse(date.format('D'))
  // Get the corresponding image from 2010
  // you also need to reduce the image collection in this case to get an Image
  var doy_2010 = evi2010.filter(ee.Filter.dayOfYear(doy, doy)).first()
  var difference = image.subtract(doy_2010)
  return difference.set('system:time_start', date)
})

print(doy_difference)
```